# Angular post service edits date time object before sending to MVC controller

Tags: angular, datetime, model-view-controller

I have a strange situation which I'm not sure how to approach. I have an ASP.NET Core Angular application in development mode. I'm sending a post request with an object to the database like this.

```
createPosition(pos)
{

    console.log(pos, "Just before we send the position to the server");

    return this.authHttp.post('/api/positions', pos)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .catch((error:Response)=>{
        return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
    });
}
```

Now, there is a date object inside the pos object and if I debug the pos object at this point in the console I get this for the value:

entryDate:Tue Aug 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Романское время (зима))

Never mind the Russian text in the brackets which states (Roman time (winter)). However in the Controller (right in the input where I get the object before any operations) I get a different time.

EntryDate [DateTime]:{31.07.2017 21:00:00}

I have no idea why that is happening...
Anyone had this problem?

The controller

```
    [HttpPost("/api/positions")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult CreatePosition([FromBody] Trade position)
    {
        //if I debug at this point I already have the weird date

        context.Trades.Add(position);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(position);
    }
```

Comment: where do you get the object time as `this point in time ` and `However in the Controller ` means  ?

Comment: The object time is a simple input from a form using Angular Material Date picker component.

Comment: and now by controller you are saying in the service method `createPosition` how do you send the value to this method is there anything that you do when you set the date to the object ? this is a problem in rest api right it is converting the date  i guess

Comment: Something weird is happening somewhere under the hood between angular service and mvc controller. The value arrives fine just before the authHttp.post method in the service, from there the next point to debug is the input in the controller method CreatePosition([FromBody] Trade position), and right there it is different. I can't debug it anywhere else in between it goes under the hood...

Comment: that is the problem in the mvc controller it is parsing the date incorrectly , you need to verfiy it there or change your angular date to that before posting

Comment: That is exactly what I trying to find out how to do beacause I have no idea what MVC does to date time objects under the hood and how to address those options. I guess what bugs it is the 00:00:00 time. It might think that it is a previous day or something like that.

Comment: what langauage do you use for your rest api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an instance as it is via REST, you need to pass a string.
I suggest you to pass the timestamp:

```
dateObject.getTime()
```

and eventually recreate the Date object in the controller with:

```
let dateObject = new Date(timestampString);
```

Comment: I just figured out that angular sets the time locally according to my client time and the MVC reads the local time and adjusts it to UTC subtracting three hours and that is why I get the difference. The controller has no problem accepting the instance, I guess I have to fiddle with timezone settings and tell it to use client timezone somehow.

Comment: The client timezone is comming in with the object into controller entryDate:Tue Aug 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Романское время (зима)) so there must be a way to tell the controller to use it and not adjust to UTC.

Comment: The problem is that if you debug the object coming into the controller it states Kind [DateTimeKind]:Utc which is true. It is the correct time. Client inputs in GMT +3 Roman TImezone and MVC saves to database the same time but in UTC format. But then, when I want to display the time to the client it gives me the UTC time from the database but the client was saving in Roman format. The info about client timezone is not passed correctly and I can't work with it.

Comment: Also it is actually not MVC who is bugging it is the Anglar Material DateTimepicker which states we have roman time in the value but if you explore the object it passes it actually passess UTC which is weird.

Comment: Instances passed via Http requests are transformed into a string by their method toString(), a stringified Date instance is still a valid Date string that can be used to recreate the instance. Anyway using timestamps will also resolve the time zone problem, since it is an international format.

Comment: Sounds like the most appropriate method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So after a workaround suggested by m_ I figured out a hack to use. I don;t care if the time is stored in UTC on the server, that is fine and is actually good because no matter where the client was, the time he entered into the database is stored in single zone format.

Next, depending on where the client is right now I get his timezone and add/subtract from the values stored in the database so the client get the most proper representation of his stored values adjusted to the local time he is in at the moment.

So here comes the code. Whenever I get any time date from the server I just do this now and it adjusts perfectly well. (this.position is my object where I have in this case the entryDate)

```
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
let entryDateFromServer = new Date(this.position.entryDate);
let timeInMs = entryDateFromServer.getTime();
var localEntryDate = new Date();
localEntryDate.setTime(timeInMs-(60000*offset));
this.position.entryDate= localEntryDate;
```

Thanks.